CMake cannot find BLAS libraries after installing OpenBLAS via Conan
I am working on a project that uses Fortran and requires BLAS libraries. I've decided to use OpenBLAS, which I installed via Conan. However, I'm encountering an issue where CMake cannot find the BLAS libraries even though OpenBLAS is installed. Here's my setup:
CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6.0)
project(test Fortran)
find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)

conanfile.txt:
[requires]
openblas/0.3.26

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain

[layout]
cmake_layout

Build Script (batch file):
RMDIR /S /Q build
MKDIR build
CD build

SET "PATH=C:\Windows\System32\;C:\Program Files\CMake\bin;C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts\;"
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\setvars.bat"
xcopy /s ..\conanfile.txt conanfile.txt
conan install ..\conanfile.txt --build=missing
cmake -G "Ninja" .. -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=ifort -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
CD ..

When I run the batch script, CMake fails to configure the project with the following error:
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find BLAS (missing: BLAS_LIBRARIES)

I have confirmed that Conan successfully installed OpenBLAS. Why did CMake not find the BLAS libraries, and how can I resolve this issue?
P.S. I have also posted this question here on CMake Discourse.

I think you might be missing passing the toolchain information like -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=.../conan_toolchain.cmake file. That file contains the paths to locate the generated xxx-config.cmake files generated by the CMakeDeps generator.

A CMake>=3.15 would be necessary to work for Conan, I see you have a lower required one in your CMakeLists.txt. Maybe for better feedback and support, a question in https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issue would be better.

@drodri when I run cmake -G "Ninja" .. -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=ifort -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=generators\conan_toolchain.cmake
I get
`CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt: (project):
Generator
Ninja

does not support platform specification, but platform
x64

was specified.`

@drodri tryinbg with cmake .. -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=ifort -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=generators\conan_toolchain.cmake I get `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:... (project):
The CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER:
ifort

is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.`

tried compiling with cmake -G "Ninja" .. -DCMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER=ifort -DBLA_VENDER=OpenBLAS to no avail.

on a side note, why CMakeUserPresets.json is generated on the root directory?!

This seems to be working on my side with conan install + cmake --preset conan-default. Lets follow up on https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues for more details.

Using the Conan toolchain
First of all, you need to specify your Conan toolchain when configuring with CMake. With the cmake_layout that you are using, you have to add this:
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=generators\conan_toolchain.cmake

Specify Ninja as the CMake generator in Conan
By the way, I see that you are using Ninja as a generator for CMake. You have to make sure that Conan is also using that. This can be set in your global config (~/.conan2/global.conf) by adding the following line:
tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja

As far as I am aware, it has to be set globally or can only be set locally when using a conanfile.py file (not .txt) in which you could specify CMakeToolchain(self, generator="Ninja").
OpenBLAS target naming
The last point is that the openblas target from Conan is not named BLAS but OpenBLAS. So in your CMakeLists.txt you have to target it as such, as detailed on the recipe page:
# ...
find_package(OpenBLAS REQUIRED)
# ...
target_link_libraries(YOUR_TARGET OpenBLAS::OpenBLAS)

